# Managing local merge dependencies used in separate on-going pull requests

Tags: git, github, rebase

Say I have the following git log:

```
A(origin:main)-B(fork:feature1)-E(feature1)
    \--------C-D(fork:feature2)/
```

Note I'm using `origin:main` instead of `origin/main` to remove confusion with the `/` to indicate merges.

Let `origin` be some Github repo that I must provide pull-requests (PRs) to in order to make any changes. Let `feature1` and `feature2` both by existing PRs made by myself on my `fork`, neither of which has been merged into `origin` yet. Let `E` be a merge commit in my local repo. Lets say `feature1` and `feature2` are fundamentally separable features (i.e. they do in fact belong in separate PRs at this point).

Now, lets say I continue working on `feature1` to fix some things, notice that there was a bug in `feature2` and I end up with something like:

```
A(origin:main)-B(fork:feature1)-E-F-G--------I(feature1)
    \--------C-D(fork:feature2)/-H(feature2)/
```

Where `H` was a bug fix and `feature1` developments are now dependent on a working `feature2` (i.e. I must keep merging or rebasing upon `feature2` to keep `feature1` working).

Finally, lets say `origin` is updated, and I fetch some things making my log:

```
A-B(fork:feature1)----E-F-G-----------I(feature1)
 \-C-D(fork:feature2)/----H(feature2)/
  \J(origin:main)
```

Now, if the standard practice for the repo is to make me rebase `feature1` and `feature2` onto `J`, how can I do this easily without messing up the history for both features? If I just rebase `feature1` onto `J`, it will cherry-pick `C`,`D`, and `H` by default. If I use the flag `--rebase-merges` this seems to be a step in the right direction, but then what do I do with `feature2`? Just `reset --hard` onto the cherry-picked version of `H` after the `rebase --rebase-merges`?

For this kind of workflow, where I'm looking to continue developing `feature1` and `feature2`, what is the recommended way of going about this if you know the PRs may not be merged anytime soon? I.e. I'd like to avoid complications with rebase and reset while trying to keep the dependencies between the two features in tact.

One thing I considered was limiting the dependency between the features to a single merge commit locally between them, and only pushing the unmerged branches to github for the PRs. I.e. I can test the working code for`feature1` dependent upon `feature2` and then rebase to remove the merge commit every time before pushing. So reworking the above into something like:

```
A-B-E-F-G-I(fork:feature1)-K(feature1)
 \-C-D-H(fork:feature2)---/
  \J(origin:main)
```

Such that a rebase of each feature onto `J` would be easy after resetting `feature1` back to `I` after stashing any locale changes and popping them back after the rebase. This still seems like a fair bit of work, and something I'd likely forget to do from time to time.

I feel like this must be fairly common, but I didn't have a good search term or phrase for this, so happy to close this if someone has better search skills than I.

Comment: I don't think you have to maintain feature2 as a PR, at least not necessary a PR from feature2 to main. From the log, it indicates feature2 will be completely part of feature1 at last. When feature2 and feature1 are both ready then, feature1's PR being merged to main will also introduce feature2 to main. If they are not ready yet, do not rebase feature1 onto main at the moment.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks for your input. Yeah, I like that as one idea. The only disadvantage I see there is you lose the separable history for `feature2`. It would make it harder to revert something from `feature2` in the future as it would be harder to find it's commits separate from `feature1`.